# Change size of fields in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

How can you change the size of a form field?

For example, see the following code:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    field = super(ContentAdmin, delf).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name == 'somefield':
      field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'someclass ' + field.widget.attrs.get('class', '')
    return field
```

but when I use this I get ContentAdmin unknown, how do I do this?

Comment: ummm, que? solamente ingles...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos in the super call:

```python
field = super(ContentAdmin, delf).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

should be:

```python
field = super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```